# Input facet components contain degenerate triangles

Tags: c++, cgal, libigl

I'm calling [IGL `trim_with_solid`](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/508cb9940f4d1e8e54137d5afe2fd2eb9c4dc672/include/igl/copyleft/cgal/trim_with_solid.h#L18) like this:

```cpp
#include <igl/copyleft/cgal/trim_with_solid.h>

// Input
Eigen::MatrixX3f m_VA;
Eigen::MatrixX3i m_FA;
Eigen::MatrixX3f m_VB;
Eigen::MatrixX3i m_FB;

// Output
Eigen::MatrixX3f m_V;
Eigen::MatrixX3i m_F;
Eigen::Matrix<bool, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> m_D;
Eigen::VectorXi m_J;

// Fill out input matrices ...

igl::copyleft::cgal::trim_with_solid(m_VA, m_FA, m_VB, m_FB, m_V, m_F, m_D, m_J);
```

#### Errors

But I'm receiving such exceptions:

> Input facet components contain degenerate triangles

> Precondition exception expression: `!k.is_degenerate_3_object()`

#### Questions

- Am I calling `trim_with_solid` correctly?
- As far as I remember, my input meshes don't have degenerate facets. However, if they do, does IGL have any tool to detect and remove degenerate facets? Thanks!

#### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot another]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the input `B` mesh i.e. `VB`/`FB` was messed up and contained degenerate triangle polygons. After fixing `B` mesh, the errors got resolved.